# Codeigniter Undefined index userID as result from model

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined-index

In my `controller` I load my model, then execute the function `getAllUserInfo()`. Basically that function just does a `SELECT` in my DB and returns the `result()`
Now back to my controller I want to check the ID of the user that the `result()` returned to my controller to the ID stored in my session. I'm doing it like so

```
$this->load->model('profile_model');
if($query = $this->profile_model->getAllUserInfo()){
    if($query['userID'] == $this->session->userdata('id')){
        //do something
    }
```

But I'm getting this error

> Message: Undefined index: userID

I checked this also on stackoverflow in the following topics, but they didn't really help me

[Codeigniter Undefined Index Online Shop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433293/codeigniter-undefined-index-online-shop)

[Undefined Index for ... existing index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760592/undefined-index-for-existing-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `result()` then it returns the object not an array

if there is a single row returned then you can do it like this

```
if($query = $this->profile_model->getAllUserInfo()){
    if($query[0]->userID == $this->session->userdata('id')){
        //do something
    }
   }
```

else you have to loop through the `$query` to check the user id in the returned result set

```
if($query = $this->profile_model->getAllUserInfo()){
 foreach($query as $q){
    if($q->userID == $this->session->userdata('id')){
        //do something
    }
    }// end foreach
    }
```

Here the is [CI AR select reference](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Comment: Yep this did the trick. You say it doesn't return an array, but you still look it up like an array with `$query[0]->userID`

Comment: but it has the objects in it not the whole array like `$query[0]['query']` this is the whole array but it `$query[0]->userID` is the object with the index